# MySQL BETWEEN operator not working for DATETIME column

Tags: mysql, between

I don't understand why the `between` operator isn't working in the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    packed DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('2018-02-24 00:00:00');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE packed = '2018-02-24 00:00:00';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE (packed BETWEEN '2018-02-00 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-00 00:00:00');
```

The first `select` query returns `1`. The second query returns `0`. Why?

MySQL version: `14.14 Distrib 5.7.21`

Comment: The 0th of february is not a valid date (and invalid dates will be replaced by 0). Replace it by the 1st.

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you very much. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on MySQL sql_mode (`STRICT_MODE`):

```
set sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE;

DROP TABLE orders;
CREATE TABLE orders (
    packed DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('2018-02-24 00:00:00');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE packed = '2018-02-24 00:00:00';
-- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders 
WHERE (packed BETWEEN '2018-02-00 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-00 00:00:00');
--0
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/PGFJB10761)**

But:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode; 
-- STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION


CREATE TABLE orders (
    packed DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('2018-02-24 00:00:00');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE packed = '2018-02-24 00:00:00';
-- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders 
WHERE (packed BETWEEN '2018-02-00 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-00 00:00:00');
-- 1
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://rextester.com/VAX59778)**

---

The correct way is to always provide valid dates.